# checking if or that?

Tags: word-choice

- In this area, we are checking **if** the pin penetrated through the wood with a sensor
- In this area, we are checking **that** the pin penetrated through the wood with a sensor

In this sentence, should I use if or that? I'm assuming a situation where I introduce my work area in the factory to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct but "if/whether" is used to express uncertainty or doubt, since "that" is used when we are certain about something.

> In this area, we are checking **if** the pin ...

It is very possible that the pin won't penetrate through the wood and we are checking if it did or not.

> In this area, we are checking **that** the pin ...

In this example, we know that the pin will almost certainly penetrate through the wood but we still check just in case it didn't.

Comment: Exactly. **Checking that** implies that you **want** the pin to penetrate the wood.,

Comment: Thank you very much!!!